# How can I activate the first line of an element when it is a pane element (UI - win32)?

Tags: python, user-interface, robotframework, win32-process

**I should get the first line in the pane activated, but I can't figure out how.**
[Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIsJE.jpg)

The screen has a pane element (/Window/Pane/Pane/Pane[1]/Pane[2]).

Clicking pane the application selects the row from the middle of the box. If I scroll up + I try to click, the window does not recognize the click.

If I click the TAB button from the previous field, the row is not activated and the click does not produce any result.

When I enter the line with TAB and take a position with the method pyautogui.position(), it gives a reading of 0, 500 (which is not correct).

And it doesn't even help to look for a position, because someone else may have a different resolution to mine.

I am using libraries OPPywinautoLibrary, FlaUILibrary and pyautogui.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.